# Accessing div in multiple div in BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm just learn BeautifulSoup and Python just around 4 days ago for my project, and now having troubles in accessing multiple div from here :

[image]

My intention is to get the value "DIY Proj Ent" from the 
, thus I tried to access via :

```
AccName = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'comProfile_hld row'})
print(AccName.get_text())
```

With this code, I got : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_Text'`

Then I change the print part into : `print(AccName)`, but got 'None' as the result.

So, how can I access the value which having multiple layer of div directly? Is beautifulsoup4 really can access div via the div name?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you post your whole codebase?

Comment: Check the page source.... is `comProfile_hld row` present there? That compound class may be dynamically generated in the webpage. Also, please use snippet tool via [edit] to share formatted html rather than post pictures we can't copy paste test.

Comment: Can you share your approach? and which website you're scraping. Many reasons that could lead to this, the website may be loaded with javascript or you're getting rate-limited by the server to avoid DDoS. Please share more details

Comment: @Sajid I'm extracting some data from here actually : https://www.bursamarketplace.com/mkt/themarket/stock/THRI/profile

Comment: @QHarr you may check in bursamarketplace.com/mkt/themarket/stock/THRI/profile

Comment: Data is loaded dynamically to the page so the value you want won't be present in a simple requests request to that url (assuming you really want full address. Parts of address may be in keywords of meta tag)

Comment: What's the actual url that produces the html you show in your question?

Comment: @QHarr this is the URL. No other URL. I want to extract the company name actually

Comment: @YuriRen you may refer to the link I mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular info comes from an ajax request you can find in network tab

https://www.bursamarketplace.com/index.php?tpl=company_ajax&type=profile_address&code=THRI.KL

So something like the following should work on the returned html

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.bursamarketplace.com/index.php?tpl=company_ajax&type=profile_address&code=THRI.KL')
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('.cttDetail_label').next_sibling.next_sibling)
```

Comment: It gives : "AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'select_one'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" , same if I replace with find() or find_all()

Comment: Did you run the code exactly as written above? I don't think you have.

Comment: I need to change your code little bit coz it asked for parser

Comment: Then just change this `soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')` to this `soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')`

Comment: buts sadly, this method cant be use to het only the website under it T.T